# Any need for BackgroundWorker if using System.Threading.Timer?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker

If I need a task to run in the background once per hour, can I just use a `Timer` object which apparently will use a separate thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdzx8wx8.aspx ?

It would seem from this that there is no need to use a `BackgroundWorker` for my purposes. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That very much depends on what your task is. The BackgroundWorker component will give you several additional features over and above the Timer, including [cancellation support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx), [progress reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) and so on. However, if you just want to kick something off every hour and don't require anything further, then the Timer is a very lightweight choice.

Have you researched using the Task Scheduler as another option? There's a neat wrapper here: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Seems like the task scheduler option would require the app to run with administrative privileges.

Comment: @CJ7 - If I remember correctly, the security Principal setting for the task will let you customise the permissions under which your task runs.